# How to know from which computer a Dropbox folder has been deleted?

Tags: dropbox

I have a folder on my Dropbox account that I share with some people. Some of them can edit the folder and delete it.

The folder disappeared today at a time none of my computers that are linked to Dropbox were turned on.

**Is there a way I can know from which computer (computer name, email address or IP) the folder was deleted?**